# getting products and their attributes from prestashop webservice

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.5

I'm going to use Prestashop 1.5.4 web-service to get all products with their attributes such as description, name and etc. My problem is whenever I call web-service it returns to me only the products Ids. How can I get attributes too?

Edited :

code :

```
class ShopApi
{
    public $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getClient();
    }

    public function getClient()
    {
        try {
            // creating web service access
            $this->client = new PrestaShopWebservice('http://wikibazaar.ir/', 'A38L095W0RHRXE8PM9CM01CZW7KIU4PX', false);
        } catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
            // Shows a message related to the error
            echo 'error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

class ProductApi extends ShopApi
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        $products = array();
        /// The key-value array
        $opt['resource'] = 'products';
        $opt['display'] = '[description]';
        $opt['limit'] = 1;
        $xml = $this->client->get($opt);
        $resources = $xml->products->children();
        foreach ($resources as $resource)
            $products[] = $resource->attributes();
        return $products;
    }
}
```

EDIT :
I've found that the response from webservice is ok. but there is a problem during parsing xml with `simplexml_load_string()` function. any idea?
it's $product var_dump :

```
SimpleXMLElement#1 ( [products] => SimpleXMLElement#2 ( [product] => SimpleXMLElement#3 ( [description] => SimpleXMLElement#4 ( [language] => SimpleXMLElement#5 ( [@attributes] => array ( 'id' => '1' ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: is your call something like `yoursite.com/api/products`   ?

Comment: i've edited my question and put my codes. yes this is the url I use.

Comment: ouh I thought you were calling the webservice from outside, it would be yoursite.com/api/products?display=full, or yoursite.com/api/products?display=[id,name] to display just id and names, hope it can help ^^

Comment: what changes I have to made in my code? i use prestaWebServiceLibrary. how to set display parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that `$opt['display'] = 'full';` would do the job
You can also select only some specific attribute e.g.

```
$opt['display'] = '[id,name]';
```

Take a look at the [official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+8+-+Advanced+Use), you might find it interesting

Comment: it works to some extend, when I set display[description] it returns description attribute but there is a language element int it with the value one.

Comment: I mean description is return 1

Comment: @hamedkh could you please post a var_dump of $products?

Comment: I've found that the response from webservice is ok. but there is a problem during parsing xml with `simplexml_load_string()` function. any idea?

Comment: thanks. my problem was soled by using  simplexml_load_string($response, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)